# Query to get rows based on dates from two table in Athena

Tags: sql, postgresql, presto

I have two table called master_tbl and anom_table 
as follows:

master_tbl

```
 date         id     country    value     
     2017-01-01   26      US        2            
     2017-01-02   26      US        4             
     2017-01-03   26      US        9             
     2017-01-04   26      US        2             
     2017-01-05   26      US        4             
     2017-01-06   26      US        1
     2017-01-07   26      US        5
     2017-01-08   26      US        3
     2017-01-09   26      US        100
     2017-01-10   26      US        4
```

anom_tbl

```
date         id  country     anoms
 2017-01-01   26      US        0
 2017-01-02   26      US        0
 2017-01-03   26      US        9
 2017-01-04   26      US        0
 2017-01-05   26      US        0
 2017-01-06   26      US        0
 2017-01-07   26      US        0
 2017-01-08   26      US        0
 2017-01-09   26      US        100
 2017-01-10   26      US        0
```

I want to create third table from master_tbl and join with anom_tbl to select only rows which  dates that has value in anom column in from anom_tbl and one day before and one day after that date from master_tbl

Finally I want to have the following table

```
date         id  country     value
 2017-01-02   26      US        2
 2017-01-03   26      US        9
 2017-01-04   26      US        4
 2017-01-08   26      US        3
 2017-01-09   26      US        100
 2017-01-10   26      US        4
```

because I have big data I takes time that I run it in R or python then I want to create table in AWS (athena)

I have tried the following code in the athena however it does not work

```
FROM 
    (SELECT t2.value,
         t1.id,
         t1.country AS country,
         cast(t1.date AS DATE) AS orig_date
    FROM 
        (SELECT id,
         country,
         date
        FROM anom_tbl) t1
        JOIN master_tbl t2
            ON t2.id=t1.id
                AND t2.country= t1.country
                AND t2.date=t1.date) t3
    JOIN master_tbl t2
    ON t3.id=t2.id
        AND t3.country=t2.country 
        where t2.date IN(GETDATE()-1)
```

Could you please help me to modify the sql code to get the proper result.

Comment: Please explain the logic you want to implement.  It is not obvious.

Comment: As I explained I want to get values from master_tbl which the value column in the anom_tbl has value NOT 0 and one day before and after that date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If* I followed you correctly, you could do this with `exists`:

```
select m.*
from master_tbl m
where exists (
    select 1
    from anom_tbl a
    where 
        a.anoms <> 0
        and a.id = m.id 
        and a.country = m.country
        and m.date >= a.date - interval '1' day
        and m.date <= a.date + interval '1' day
)
```

This brings all records in the master table for which another record exists in the anom table for the same id and country, with a non-0 value, within a +/- 1 day interval.

Comment: thanks could you please let me know what does exists do

Comment: @user: I just updated my answer with a short explanation.

Comment: It works well however you need to add = sign in the "
and m.date <  a.date + interval '1' day"